# swift 3 iOS tableview datasource memory

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caching, memory-management

I have a tableview which acts as a newsfeed. The cells are filled from an array of newsfeed items. I get the JSON from the Server, create newsfeed items from that input and attach them to my newsfeed array. a newsfeed item contains a title, a description and an imageurl string.

At:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageFeedItemTableViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! ImageFeedItemTableViewCell
    var item = self.feed!.items[indexPath.row]
    if (item.messageType == 1){
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageFeedItemTableViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! ImageFeedItemTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = item.title
    cell.description.text = item.contentText

    if (item.imageURL as URL == URL(string: "noPicture")!)
    {
      cell.picture.image = UIImage(named:"empty")
    }
    else{

    if (item.cachedImage == UIImage(named:"default-placeholder")){
    let request = URLRequest(url: item.imageURL as URL)
    cell.picture.image = item.cachedImage
    cell.dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                if (image != nil){
              self.feed!.items[indexPath.row].cachedImage = image!
                }
                cell.picture.image = image


             }

        })

    }) 
        cell.dataTask?.resume()
    }else
    {
        cell.picture.image = item.cachedImage
    }
    }


}
```

the cells from the rows get filled with my newsfeeditem data.

But since i keep all my newsfeeditems inside an array, the memory usage is high and gehts higher for each additional newsfeeditem. I want it to work with endless scrolling like twitter, so i wonder how experienced developers tackle this memory issue.

Comment: please add the cellForRowAt method as a code snippet

Comment: i have added the missing code!

Comment: pagination is a good way to implemented if there are lots of feeds

Comment: i thought about that as well. what kind of pagination? page index numbers look outdated, so i thought about twitter, they load new tweets when you reach the bottom, but you can scroll up again without loading, which means that they save the data somewhere and i wonder where since keeping all tweets in memory would crash the app i guess.

Comment: normal data can be saved in array. but information like images can be fetched and set. Kingfishers and alamofireImage can help cache it too.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this lines or wherever you try to hold `UIImage` inside your array, this is really not advised and will cause crash due to memory since image is very large data and not advised to persist it in your RAM with `UIImage` inside array:

`self.feed!.items[indexPath.row].cachedImage = image!`

What you need to do is basically after fetch your image from URL, you save it to your app's documents folder and save the name or it's path that can distinct your image in `cachedImage` (just change the type to string or sth) and refetch it from your app's document folder when you need to show it in `cellForRow`

Flow: Fetch image -> save to disk and persist path in array -> refetch from disk with the path in `cellForRow`

Comment: Ok i heard that i can reach that behaviour using SDWebImage, is that right? But what if i never had an image inside the cell, the memory would rise even with text only newsfeed items doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, `SDWebImage` will help you do all the step above with little code

Comment: i edited my answer just seconds before you answered, sorry

Comment: Because the memory is not from the cell, but from the array, its your array that make this behavior and raise your memory, the cell is just showing whatever is holding in your array

Comment: how can i make the items from the array only load into the memory when needed?

Comment: You cant, array is persist in RAM until your viewcontroller is deallocated, you have to persist as little resource as possible, thats why im telling you to store the image to disk and save it's path into your array

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher, If you are worried about the memory footprint caused by saving a large amount of text you can also use some third-party caching lib such as [this](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache). But, as always, before complicating things you should carefully measure current memory usage with the help of Xcode profile tools.